# How to go through a python list one by one?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to make an algorithm that finds which number is out of order in a group of numbers.

Is there a way to go through the list and see if adding 1 to each item on the list makes the value of the next item on the list. Example ( 0 + 1 == 1) and ( 1 + 1 = 2) but when you get to (2 + 1 != 4) how would I make it display a 3.

```
number = [0,1,2,4,5]

if number[0] + 1 != number[1]:
```

Comment: yes, it is very possible, what do you mean by _how would I make it display 3_? where do you want to display it? why and what is the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare each number with its relative position (starting at the first value):

```
if any(i!=n for i,n in enumerate(a,a[0])):
   print("out of order")
else:
   print("proper sequence")
```

You could also use zip to compare each item with its successor:

```
if any(m-n != 1 for n,m in zip(a,a[1:])):
   print("out of order")
else:
   print("proper sequence")
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC: I would suggest using the built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function and a copy of the list which starts from the second item to get the current and next item in the list:

```py
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5]

for c_number, n_number in zip(numbers, numbers[1:]):
    if c_number + 1 != n_number:
        print(c_number + 1)
```

Or even better use [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) (only if you have Python 3.10 or newer, but otherwise you can take a look at the *roughly equivalent* in the link above to create the same functionality):

```py
import itertools

numbers = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5]

for c_number, n_number in itertools.pairwise(numbers):
    if c_number + 1 != n_number:
        print(c_number + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant say that I understand what the logic is, when you want to print 3. But anyway here is how to do it, use the code accordingly:

```
a = [0,1,2,4,5]

for i in range(len(a)-1):
   if a[i] + 1 != a[i+1]:
      print(a[i]+1)
```

Or if you are looking to add the missing field into the list, you can do that in the following way:

```
for i in range(a[0], a[-1]):
    if a[i] + 1 != a[i+1]:
       a.insert(a[i]+1,a[i]+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer this  approach:
Instead of checking if the next value is by one bigger than the current,
iterate through every number from the lowest to the highest in the list and check if it's there.

```
my_list = [0,1,2,4,5,8,9]

for i in range(min(my_list), max(my_list) + 1):
    if i not in my_list:
        print(i)
```

This only works with the condition that each value is by one larger than the previous or if the interval between the values remains constant, in which case, the interval needs to be included in the range-function like this:
`range(start, stop, step)`

Comment: btw tho, OP clearly stated that they need to check if the next item matches the condition

Comment: I personally find that approach to be less elegant for the goal of finding the missing values. Of course, my solution won't work, once the condition changes

Comment: You make too many assumptions about the question. For example, the neighbour elements can be different only by 1 or 2. Try to run your code with
my_list = [0,1,2,4,5,8,19]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to go through every number by using the "for loop":

```
numbers = [0,1,2,4,5] #your numbers

for i in range(0, len(numbers)): #go through every number
    if numbers[i] + 1 != number[i+1]: #check if number is not in the line
        print(str(i)+"is false") #output
```